# Extract source code on the fly to a file?

Tags: floats, environments, programming, minted

I'm trying to create a programming text to use for my students. My goal is to have an environment (say, "`code`", for instance), so, if I type the following in my `.tex` file:

```
\begin{code}{Sample script}
echo "Hi there<br/>";
\end{code}
```

then I get the following:

1. In my `.tex` file, as if I had written:

   ```
   \begin{figure}        
   \begin{minted}{php}
   echo "Hi there<br/>";
   \end{minted}
   \caption{\href{\thefigure{}.php}{Sample script}}
   \end{figure}
   ```
2. Auto-generated `\thefigure{}.php` file (that is, the file name follows the figure counter numeric value, `1.3.php` for instance) in the same directory as my `.tex` file, containing the code I wrote between `\begin{code}` and `\end{code}`.

My goal is to extract all my programming codes to `.php` files linked from the book.

Is that possible?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome, i am pretty sure  `minted` can do the numbering itself, without putting stuff in a figure environment.

Comment: I don't know whether `minted` allows this, but `tcolorbox` does!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll take a look at `tcolorbox` as well as a deep breath in `minted` ;-).

Comment: Perhaps consider an architecture that actually runs the php code somewhere, whether or not you need its output in the document. With this structure the code in your TeX file hasn't been tested. One possibility it to write the code to a file (there are tools for this), then run it (with a shell escape) and include the file with the listings package.

Comment: @EthanBolker, you're absolutely right. Using a linter before inserting the php code into the book is a good thing.

Comment: If you're looking to write an extended document (say, a book) in this fashion, you may be interested in [literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming). I believe [noweb](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/) is the standard cross-language tool. Some languages have language-specific literate programming tools as well, like [Haskell's](https://wiki.haskell.org/Literate_programming) `lhs2tex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the following solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman,es-noindentfirst]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[minted,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[pdftex,unicode,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{veelo}

\title{Text}
\author{Me}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section]{php}[1][\url{code/\thetcbcounter.php}]{
    listing engine=minted,%minted style=colorful,
    minted language=php,minted options={fontsize=\small,linenos,numbersep=3mm,startinline},
    listing file=code/\thetcbcounter.php,
    run system command={./linter.sh php \thetcbcounter},
    colback=blue!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,listing only,breakable,
    left=8mm,enhanced,title=\textbf{Listado~\thetcbcounter:} \href{code/\thetcbcounter.php}{#1},
    before title={\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}},
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red!20!blue!20!white] (frame.south west)
             rectangle ([xshift=8mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\part{Basics}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Testing 123}

\lipsum

\begin{php}[Test]
class Products extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('products/index');
    }
}
\end{php}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

With the following `linter.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

fn_php()
{
    mv $1.php $1
    echo "<?php\n" | cat - $1 > $1.php
    php -l $1.php 2> $1.linter
    php -l $1.php
}

cd code
if [ "$1" = "php" ]
then
    fn_php $2
fi
cd ..
```

My solution meets all the goals I set for. It generates external files extracting the contains from the `\begin{php}` ... `\end{php}` environment, and then checks its syntax using `php -l`. Hope this helps for another ;).

Thanks very much for all your help!

Answer (score 7):

I do it the other way around: Include the code (using the `listings` package, I'm sure `minted` is similar) and include it into the document. With the keys `firstline` and `lastline` you can select the exact range to show.

Comment: +1 This is a good approach: I was thinking to use TeX's capabilities to write to external files, but it makes more sense to write the code separately, exactly as it should be formatted as code, and then just have LaTeX typeset it.

Comment: Yes, and as per my earlier comment: use a shell escape to run the code, and, if you wish, collect the output and include it.

Comment: @EthanBolker what I do (under Linux) is to compile/run the code "normally" from a `Makefile` as needed, which also builds the document(s).

Comment: Just for reference, I think the alternate approach would be to wrap the code in filecontents environments to write them to files.

Comment: @AndrewCashner, that is a nice trick to package up the files, true. But I prefer to ship tarballs around, and even more to keep them in git repositories.